# Processing JSON retrieved with curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using curl function to get the data from gotowebinar url.  here is the code

```
 $data=curl_exec($curl);


   @curl_close($curl);

   $newdata=json_decode($data, true);
   print_r($newdata);
```

I am getting this output:

```
[
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-07-11T16:54:11Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-07-05T23:55:23Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-07-11T23:27:56Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@visioninvesting.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-07-11T23:29:40Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-07-11T18:14:32Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    {
        "registrantKey": 12345,
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "1",
        "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
        "status": "WAITING",
        "registrationDate": "2012-06-29T21:07:10Z",
        "joinUrl": "https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123/456",
        "timeZone": "America/Denver"
    }
]
```

I used `json_decode` to format the data but it did not work. I want to format the output so that I can use its values in program.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! "it did not work" is generally not a very good description of what you're having problems with. What's the exact issue, what are you trying, and what are you expecting? You're obviously not having any issue with the code to fetch your JSON so maybe that's not so interesting to see? =)

Comment: yes i am getting output. but i want to use its value in my programme. Like i want to store registrant key, first name,last name etc in different variables and then these variable can be used in php.

Comment: Okay - you may want to edit your question and remove the uninteresting bits - your curl-code for instance, that actually works - and add in the code you have for where you try to parse the JSON into variables so we can have a look and help you.

Comment: Yes, how exactly did you try to decode the response? The return value will be an array of objects, which you then can iterate over and process in any way you want. What exactly are you having problems with? Maybe the examples in the documentation already help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $data=curl_exec($curl);
  
   //$info = @curl_getinfo($curl);
   @curl_close($curl);
   
   $newdata=json_decode($data, true);
   print_r($newdata);
   //print_r($info);

Comment: this is how i am trying to decode it.@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $data=curl_exec($curl);
  
   //$info = @curl_getinfo($curl);
   @curl_close($curl);
   
   $newdata=json_decode($data, true);
   print_r($newdata);
   //print_r($info);

Comment: Rather than responding in the comments, edit the question to contain your new code (and remove the non-relevant curl code as @J. Steen mentioned).  It would probably be of value to us to show the output of that code, and explain how it differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: You really shouldn't post personal data of other people in your question.

Comment: So `$newdata` will contain an array and you can work with that. If you don't know how to do this, you should read about some PHP basics first, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Comment: $newdata seems to be an array of objects. What is the format you were expecting?

Comment: Please update this with the output you are expecting.  Specifically, what do you mean when you say "I want to format the output so that I can use its values in program."  Thanks!

Comment: $name=Rohan; 
$email=rohankapoor99@yahoo.com

i wnt to assign each value to the variable so that i can use it in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple PHP code for looping over the resulting object from calling `json_decode`.

```
$newdata = json_decode($data);

foreach($newdata as $entry) {
    echo "{$entry->firstName} is {$entry->status}.  " .
         "Their key is {$entry->registrantKey}.<br />\n";
}
```

You can access any of the properties you see in the returned json from the decoded object.

Since you get an array of objects, you can loop over each entry (as shown above), or access a specific entry like this:

```
$third = $newdata[2]->firstName;
```

Hope that helps get you started.

Comment: I took the JSON you posted directly and ran it successfully.  See http://codepad.org/kmRZ0J3G  When it "did not work" did you get any output, specific error messages or what?

Comment: Check the [codepad](http://codepad.org/kmRZ0J3G) post and you can see it working.  Hopefully you can get it working with the actual code you are using...

Comment: i want output like this:
$name=Rohan;
$email:ankpro15@yahoo.com; 

so that i can use variables in my program.

Comment: My answer shows how to use the variables in your program.  If you want them to be called `$name` and `$email` etc, then you will have to re-assign them to those variables from the values in the decoded JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to an array first:

```
$newdata = (array) json_decode($data, true);
```